# Full-Text Indexing in MySql to speed up "contains" searches

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am running into issues, since I have very large tables, doing updates that are based on where clauses with `like % X` or `like '% X %`. I even got to the point where I considered "exploding" the Name fields into NameWord1, NameWord2 so I can construct what would be more complex where clauses but each would at least be '=' vs 'like %'.

I noticed however full-text indexes and am not clear in the documentation if these might achieve the same result. I am loathe to full-text index the multi-million records table to test and I can't see a test on a small table giving me any real insights into performance gains so I am posting what I realize is somewhat of a generic question here to get some feedback on MySql Full-Text indexes applicability to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general answer, "yes".  Your use-case is what full-text indexes are designed for.

Two things to keep in mind as you implement one:

- The minimum word length.  The default is 3 or 4 depending on the storage engine.  If you are looking for one character, then this is clearly too long.  (See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).)
- Stop word list.  These are values that are not in the index, either because they are uninformative ("nevertheless") or too common ("have").

Also, if your `where` clause contains other conditions, then the full text index may not be as great an improvement as it otherwise would be.

And, one final note.  If the column you are indexing is really a list of *codes*, then these should be in a junction table.  Although full-text indexing could provide a benefit, a proper data structure with appropriate indexes would have even better performance -- and you could maintain relational integrity as well.

Comment: The min word length actually is an issue. Mainly what I am doing is trying to create IDs for address fields and most of that replacement has to do with directions (N, E, NE) and street types (St, Ave, Pl). Sphinx works for me great in the actual search since I can use wordforms so that a search for `N Main St` matches `North Main Street` but trying to get various tables to standardize stored tables so the former in TableA and the latter in TableB both have the same streetID and can be related is the issue.